# Cakephp: How to retrieve video url from Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cakephp

**Uploading Video**:

```
require_once 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php';  
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

$gs_name = $file1['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($gs_name, 'gs://bucketname/videos/' . $file_name);
```

**Fetching Video:**

```
$file_url = CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl("gs://bucketname/videos/20150225074324830.mp4", true);
```

I am not able to fetch the video, please let me know how to fetch the video from Google App Engine. Successfully fetched the images from google app engine by :

```
$image_url = CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl('gs://bucketname/avatars/' . $user['User']['id'] . '/' . $user['User']['avatar']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the issue, code to fetch the video is:

```
$file_url = CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl("gs://bucketname/videos/20150225074324830.mp4", true);
```

Problem is that I have to mark the video as public by writing following code:

```
$storeAt="gs://bucketname/videos/20150225074324830.mp4";
$options = array('gs'=>array('acl'=>'public-read','Content-Type' =>   $file['type']));
$ctx = stream_context_create($options);
$saved = file_put_contents($storeAt, file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']), 0, $ctx);
```

[image]